# JPA Query for ManyToOne with multiple entities in one entity?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, many-to-one

I have some sort of scenario. Let's say that I'm making a database about games. So first, I have Three entities: `Company`, `Platform` and `Game`.

`Company` goes like this:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "company")
public class Company implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "MA_COMPANY_ID_S")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "MA_COMPANY_ID_S", allocationSize = 1, sequenceName = "MA_COMPANY_ID_S")
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "COMPANY_NAME")
    private String companyName;
}
```

`Platform` goes like this

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "platform")
public class Platform {
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "MA_PLATFORM_ID_S")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "MA_PLATFORM_ID_S", allocationSize = 1, sequenceName = "MA_PLATFORM_ID_S")
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "PLATFORM_NAME")
    private String platformName;
}
```

And finally, `Game` goes like this

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "game")
public class Game {
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "MA_GAME_ID_S")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "MA_GAME_ID_S", allocationSize = 1, sequenceName = "MA_GAME_ID_S")
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "GAME_NAME")
    private String gameName;

    @Column(name="TEST")
    private String testName;

    @ManyToOne 
    @JoinColumn(name="COMPANY_ID",
            foreignKey=@ForeignKey(name="FK_COMPANY_ID"))
    private Company company;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="PLATFORM_ID",
            foreignKey=@ForeignKey(name="FK_PLATFORM_ID"))
    private Platform platform;
}
```

As you can see, a game has to have two foreign keys linking to a company and a platform, as in, a game is produced by one company and then put on a platform (put aside the notions of multiplatform later)

I use a repository file to connect this with my database. I'll just list the `GameRepository` example because this is where the problem comes in

```
@Repository
public interface GameRepository extends JpaRepository<Game, Long> {
    @Query("SELECT id, gameName, company, platform FROM Game g WHERE g.id = :id")
    public Game findGameById(@Param("id") String id);
}
```

If I run my program, I get this error instead:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.IdentNode 
 \-[IDENT] IdentNode: 'platform' {originalText=platform}
```

However, if I only stick with only ONE `@ManyToOne` variable in the query, like if I remove either the `company` or `platform` (for example: `"SELECT id, gameName, company FROM Game g WHERE g.id = :id"`, the query WORKS.

Where did I go wrong, is it possible to have multiple `@ManyToOne` relationship that refer to multiple entities within ONE entity and make it run? Or should I have stuck with `@ManyToMany`? If so, how?

Thanks!

Comment: Once you're using Spring Data JPA why are you writing a query that is already provided by JpaRepostiory? I think you can just use `findById`.

Comment: However, if you want to keep this method, have you tried this `select g from Game g where g.id = :id`?

Comment: It's only as a most basic query so I can know what to do or what not to do as I go to the more complex queries. Anyway, Roman has answered that it's not about ManyToOne and ManyToMany, the query works. If I have to be more specific on the company/platform, HQL allows for JOIN method. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As Bruno Alves commented, there are 2 solutions for this problem

1. Try naming the method to *getById(long id)*, so Spring Data generates the required query for you. Query annotation is not needed for this solution
2. Maybe your HQL request is wrong? Try *select g from Game g where g.id = :id*

ManyToOne/ManyToMany do not matter for your request